# Execute jQuery after Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, jsp, web-applications, richfaces

The text on a JSP-PAge is trimmed by the jQuery Text Overflow Plugin.
The Script is executed after the page has loaded but not after the Ajax-Request (Switching Tabs). How to ensure its functionality in this case?

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax" ...>
<rich:tab>...</rich:tab>
<rich:tab>...</rich:tab>
...
</rich:tabPanel>

<script type="text/javascript">

var text_to_trim = jQuery('.table_modul td, .docs_links li, .shoppingCart li');
jQuery(text_to_trim).textOverflow(null, true); //Text Overflow Plugin

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Defined a named jQuery function using rich:jQuery and then call it via oncomnplete=namedJQueryFunction();